# v-model in textarea / Editing state

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a comments component which shows all the comments .

the user can edit the comment.

I'm trying to get the comment in v-model so the user can edit it .

```
       <div v-if="editing == comment.id && editingMode == true" :key="comment.id">
            <textarea
              class="form-control"
              :class="{ 'is-invalid': editError.length > 0 }"
              v-model="comment.body"
              :id="comment.id"
              @input="removeEdit"
              :placeholder="comment.body"
            >{{ comment.body }}</textarea>
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" v-if="editError.length > 0">
              <small>{{ editError.toString() }}</small>
            </span>
            <br />
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" @click="editComment(comment)">save</button>
            <loading :active.sync="loadingEdit" :is-full-page="false"></loading>
          </div>
```

the code above is inside `v-for` :

```
 <div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" v-if="comment.parent == null">
```

I have `comment.body` in `data()`

```
 comment: {
        body: "",
        id: "",
      },
```

when i click edit i see the comment in the textarea but when i click save the editComment method fetchs the comments again and the comment is not getting saved .

editcomment method :

```
   editComment(comment) {
      this.editingMode = true;
      this.loadingEdit = true;
      axios
        .put(`/comment/${this.post}/${comment.id}/reply/user/update`, {
          comment: this.comment.body
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.editingMode = false;
          this.fetchComments();
          this.loadingEdit = false;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.loadingEdit = false;

        });
    },
```

the problem is not in my backend code .

When i hit save i can see in vue tools that the comment.body is getting reset to the old value.

when i console.log  the `comment.body` in `editComment()` i can see the new value . 
Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing the `comment` property defined on the component with the `comment` variable declared inside the `v-for`. So `v-model="comment.body"` references the `comment` loop variable, was this intended?

So now `this.comment.body` in the method will always be an empty string, as opposed to `comment.body`.

What is the purpose of the `comment` data property? I would expect this is so that you can only edit one comment at a time and it will contain data related to the comment being edited, but you are binding to the individual `comment.body` in the template and passing the loop `comment` object to `editComment()`, so that isn't the case.

Comment: i changed it to comment.body and it works :\ . why this. does not work? `was this intended?` YES

Comment: I'm handling the edit like this `<div v-if="editing == comment.id && editingMode == true" >` setting the editing to comment id onclick